# Windows Application is getting closed on reopening a dialog window

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

In my application, there is a main window to create a pass. There is a Show Report button in that screen to see the report. On click of that button, show the report in a window. Parent window should be shown in the background. This is working fine, but after closing the report window again if I click the Show Report button, application is getting closed.

Code on click of Show Button

```
GatePassSummary summary = new GatePassSummary();
summary.ShowDialog(this);
```

In the report window, there is a button to close that window

```
GatePassForm form1 = new GatePassForm();
form1.Show();
```

Comment: I have a question, why do you Show the parent window when closing the child? Is it hidden? There's no need to show it again. just close it. Or maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @DanialSa'adati Parent window is the main window to create new passes. So it will be shown in the background when the report window is loaded. Hope you are clear.

Comment: So when closing the report window, you just need a `Close();` on the closebutton_click(). Sorry If I got misunderstood again. I think you may need to reword your question.

Comment: @DanialSa'adati Report window, I need to close or hide. The issue is after closing/hiding once, clicking on the same Show Report button in the main window closes the application.

Comment: I think we all need to see the `GetPassSummary.ShowDialog`